# Facebook app secret was leaked. Is there a way to invalidate all access tokens for all users?

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

My facebook app's secret was recently obtained by a malicious party.  They subsequently approved my app for thousands of user accounts, either that they created or that they also gained access to nefariously.  They then started posting spam on behalf of these people, but also on behalf of my app (e.g. Spotify posting you liked a song, it's still a post from you, but it's via the Spotify app and not explicitly from you.)

I have changed my app secret, but it seems that the existing tokens that were already obtained are still valid, as the spam keeps being posted.

Is there a way to invalidate all access tokens for my app, for both valid and invalid users (I have no way of distinguishing between the two)?  Is that the right approach to fixing this mess?

Comment: There is a question here which discusses a similar issue but does not really address your concern directly - although you can learn about the best practices from there -http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19989/facebook-api-app-secret-possible-misuse

Comment: You can not invalidate access tokens directly. But you can revoke all permissions a user granted to your app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions Of course then next time the real user wants to use your app, they would have to grant all permissions again.

Comment: How would I go about revoking all permissions for all users?  Facebook explicitly says you can only get a count of users who have authorized your app, not any information about them individually.  So it seems like doing this on a per-user basis is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There is something interesting I found on the [Login Security Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#appsecret) from the Facebook Docs. Theoretically, if you were to update the App Type settings to Native/Desktop, Facebook will stop accepting calls from Tokens which would work in your case for both valid and invalid users.

> We recommend that App Access Tokens should only be used directly from
>   your app's servers in order to provide the best security. For native
>   apps, we suggest that the app communicates with your own server and
>   the server then makes the API requests to Facebook using the App
>   Access Token.
>
> For this reason, if your 'App Type' under Advanced
>   Settings in the App Dashboard is set to Native/Desktop we assume that
>   your native app contains the App Secret or an App Access Token in the
>   binary, and we do not allow calls signed with an App Access Token to
>   proceed. The API will behave as though no access token was provided.

Here are some precautionary measures you could do as per [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/security)

Change this setting below

> Advanced > Stream post URL security this will stop your app from
>   publishing any URLs that don't point back to a domain it owns.

In addition you can check on these settings as well:

> IP Address Whitelist
>
> We allow you to specify a whitelist of IP addresses that must be used
>   to update the app settings. This helps prevent attacks by ensuring
>   that only developers using the company IP addresses can update app
>   settings.
>
> This whitelist can be set in the Advanced tab of your app settings in
>   the App Dashboard.
>
> Once specified, any app update request coming from a non-whitelisted
>   IP address is rejected. This whitelist applies to updates made using
>   API as well as the UI.

There is also information there about Update Notification which you can follow.

Comment: @BobLauer Did this answer help you , are you looking for any further clarifications?